# Historical miner fees per transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, blockchain.info, history

Where can I find accurate data showing the average amount that people paid in miner transaction fees per transaction per day?

I found a chart titled [Fees Per Transaction (USD)](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/charts/fees-usd-per-transaction) on Blockchain.com. I downloaded the dataset (csv) and calculated the average daily fee per transaction in 2021 to be $10.22.

But that doesn't make sense. I usually spend 1-3 s/B. If the volume is abnormally high, then maybe I spend at most 20 s/B. I don't think I've ever spent more than $1 for a bitcoin transaction in 2021, but the data on blockchain.com suggests that the day with the lowest average fee per transaction in all of 2021 was $1.51. How is this possible?

Why is the data reported by blockchain.com for average transaction fee per transaction so high? Where can I find accurate data that shows the average transaction fee per transaction?

Comment: See also here: https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html#alltime
They have median, too: https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-median_transaction_fee.html#alltime

If you don't trust the data then I suppose you could scan the blockchain yourself and multiply it with some average BTCUSD price for the day.